# Time until next bus

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

You arrive at a bus stop where buses come at a rate of $3$ per hour. What's the probability distribution of the waiting time for the next bus and its mean if the interarrival times between buses are

(a) constant,

(b) exponential,

(c) either 0 or 60 minutes (groups of 3 buses go by in an hour).

---

I can guess that the mean waiting time for constant is just $c/2$ where $c$ is the constant. In exponential distribution it will be just $\lambda$. Not so sure about the third one.

But getting these means doesn't help me find the distribution. Can anyone suggest me how to do it? I think you need to use the equilibrium distribution, but where do we use the fact that buses come at $3$ per hour? Do I even need this for the constant case?

Answer (score 1):

Assume without loss of generality that the buses in each group of $3$ are ordered. The probability of the *next bus* being the second or third is *zero*, since there is no gap between the group's buses. Effectively they may be treated as a single bus that comes once an hour, whereupon the expected waiting time is half an hour.

Comment: @joesx It's the same as (a).

Comment: @joesx The interarrival time in (c) is _always_ 60 minutes. Which means the time until the next bus is uniformly distributed between 0 and 60 minutes.